# DataContractJsonSerializer generating Ghost string to JSON keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

[DataContractJsonSerializer](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/218001.aspx) this is nice class added in the .net framework which can be used to serialize/desirealize object into JSON.

Now following is the example i am trying

```
[Serializable] class User { public string name;     public string userId; }
```

Now following is the output generated

Output : Notice structure where only "name" is expected instead of k__BackingField

Now this is the problem after digging so much i am not sure from where <> and _BackingField is coming ?

```
{
"<name>k__BackingField":"test user",
"<userId>k__BackingField":100001}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an educated guess. I think it's because you're using public fields instead of properties for name and userid.

Edit: It appears it also has to do with the fact that you are using the [Serializable] attribute instead of [DataContract] and [DataMember]. Check out this post for more detail:

[C# automatic property deserialization of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945585/c-automatic-property-deserialization-of-json)

Comment: Thanks for answering ........ i figured out that the C# 3.0's implicit properties causing it as compiler adds code for doing that. This is getting reflected when serialization takes place.