# JSON.NET Deserialization in C# results in empty object

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to populate a C# object (ImportedProductCodesContainer) with data using JSON.NET deserialization.

ImportedProductCodesContainer.cs:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public class ImportedProductCodesContainer
{
    public ImportedProductCodesContainer()
    {

    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public ActionType Action { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProductListRaw { get; set; }


    public enum ActionType {Append=1, Replace};
}
```

JSON string:

```
{"ImportedProductCodesContainer":{"ProductListRaw":"1 23","Action":"Append"}}
```

C# Code:

```
 var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
 var importedProductCodesContainer = 
     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImportedProductCodesContainer>(argument);
```

The problem is that *importedProductCodesContainer* remains empty after running the code above (Action = 0, ProductListRaw = null). Can you please help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many levels of `ImportedProductCodesContainer`. It's creating a new `ImportedProductCodesContainer` object (from the templated deserializer) and then attempting to set a property on it called `ImportedProductCodesContainer` (from the top level of your JSON) which would be a structure containing the other two values. If you deserialize the inner part only

```
{"ProductListRaw":"1 23","Action":"Append"}
```

then you should get the object you're expecting, or you can create a new struct with an ImportedProductCodesContainer property

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public class ImportedProductCodesContainerWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public ImportedProductCodesContainer ImportedProductCodesContainer { get; set; }
}
```

and template your deserializer with that then your original JSON should work.

It may also be possible to change this behaviour using other attributes / flags with that JSON library but I don't know it well enough to say.