# Deserialize json string

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

```
{"terms":["text",["video",4823,"videov",378,"vido",168,"videotckupload",156,"virginia",108,"videoconferenc",90,"videovv",90,"viewer",66,"videosit",54,"videosort",54]]}
```

How to design a class which would hold the values after deserialization? I am using JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# automatic property deserialization of JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945585/c-automatic-property-deserialization-of-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
class A
{
     public object[] terms {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But how do i get the values video,4823,videov.. ?

Comment: The structure of the json is a bit problematic, as it has multiple types in an array, like string and array, string and number. If the json will always be in this structure you can use "deserializedVar.terms[1]" to get the inner array.

Comment: Yes thats the problem over here, multiple types in an array. Ok! Will iterate through each object and will get the values Thanks! :)