# Is the implementation of Auto Properties in the spec?

Tags: c#, .net, automatic-properties, specifications

Can I rely on the fact that the underlying field to a property named Foo is called "k__BackingField" ?

Comment: Re Hessian; why does it care about field names? property names would be more appropriate, no? If not, perhaps invent an attribute to name the member, i.e. [Hessian.Storage("foo")] public int Foo {get;private set;}

Comment: I'd rather just implement the hack of canonizing the name (<Foo>k__backingField --> Foo) - it's easier on clients.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with auto-properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371398/problems-with-auto-properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in short.

And for this very reason, auto-properties are pain when used with field-based serializers like `BinaryFormatter` (I'm sure I might have mentioned that here before ;-p).

See: [Obfuscation, serialization and automatically implemented properties](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html) for some thoughts on this (and a solution).

Answer (score 3):

That the spec does not specify the backing field's name (with good reason - you shouldn't take a dependency on it).

You should investigate to see whether the Mono compiler does the same thing for example.

Sanity checking that the field had the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` applied to it would be a good idea.

Note that explicit interface implementations would come out (currently) as:

```
<Full.Namespace.To.Interface.IBlah.Foo>k__BackingField
```

So code which is trying to serialize a specific aspect of a class in this fashion could be mislead.

If you wanted to be really belt and braces about your code you could use a library like mono's Cecil to inspect the get function of the property and determine the field used.

Comment: I just want it to work for me on Windows, nothing too fancy - but checking the attribute is an excellent idea, thanks.

Comment: I think its safe with explicit implementation as well, since the very name of the explicitly implemented property follows the pattern `Full.Namespace.To.Interface.IBlah.Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. That would be a *private* implementation detail.

And why on Earth would you want to know?

Comment: Fixing a bug in Hessian's serialization. Auto properties are not serialized correctly, because they use the field's names.

Comment: "Hessian's serialization"? Link, please? Never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you need the backing field, use a 'regular' property.