# C# properties: how to use custom set property without private field?

Tags: c#, properties

I want to do this:

```
public Name
{
    get;
    set
    {
        dosomething();
        ??? = value
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use the auto-generated private field? 

Or is it required that I implement it this way:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        dosomething();
        name = value
    }
}
```

Comment: There is lots of good discussion on this at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277018/c-3-0-automatic-properties-what-would-be-the-name-of-private-variable-create

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Once you want to do anything custom in either the getter or the setter you cannot use auto properties anymore.

Answer (score 46):

You can try something like this:

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
public void SetName(string value)
{
    DoSomething();
    this.Name = value;
}
```

Comment: +1 To my mind this answer rebukes the accepted answer. It is using auto properties. It explicitly sets setter to private. This is a good thing because it lets the end user or developer know there is likely more going on behind the setter method.

Comment: What's the difference between this and not having set at all?

Comment: @SidhinSThomas not providing a `private set` would prevent the property from being set by its class's members; it would be strictly read-only.  You would only be able to set its data in the constructor.

Answer (score 23):

As of C# 7, you could use expression body definitions for the property's `get` and `set` accessors.

[See more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties)

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    {
        DoSomething();
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still using a private field though. Doesn't really help the OP.

Comment: While this works, it's like @TSmith says, it's not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 18):

This is not possible. Either auto implemented properties or custom code.

Answer (score 10):

It is required that you implement it fully given your scenario. Both `get` and `set` must be either auto-implemented or fully implemented together, not a combination of the two.