# what is the automatic variable name of an auto-implemented properties

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do this:

```
public string LangofUser 
    { 
       get 
       { 
          return string.IsNullOrEmpty("how to get value?") ? "English" : "how to get value?"; 
       } 
       set; 
     }
```

do I have to do this?

```
string _LangofUser
public string LangofUser 
     { 
       get 
       { 
         return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_LangofUser) ? "English" : _LangofUser; 
       } 
       set { _LangofUser = value};
     }
```

Comment: You have to do it the second way. The first is not possible.

Comment: "what is the automatic variable name of an auto-implemented properties" The backing field is anonymous. That means it doesn't have a name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# properties: how to use custom set property without private field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833635/c-sharp-properties-how-to-use-custom-set-property-without-private-field)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This mixing of auto-implement and not-auto-implemented properties in C# is not possible.  A property must be fully auto-implemented or a normal property.

Note: Even with a fully auto-implemented property there is no way to reference the backing field from C# source in a strongly typed manner.  It is possible via reflection but that's depending on implementation details of the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, don't try to mix automatic and regular properties. Just write a regular property.

If you want to know what secret names we generate behind the scenes for hidden compiler magic, see

[Where to learn about VS debugger 'magic names'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names/2509524#2509524)

but do not rely on that; it can change at any time at our whim.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your own implementation of the property, it's not automatic any more.  So yes, you need to do create the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question 
[What's the difference between encapsulating a private member as a property and defining a property without a private member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267144/whats-the-difference-between-encapsulating-a-private-member-as-a-property-and-de)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the automatic property and still have a default value, why don't you initialize it in your constructor?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() { LangOfUser = "English"; }
    public string LangOfUser { get; set; }
}
```

Since C# 6, you can also set a default value for a property as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string LangOfUser { get; set; } = "English";
}
```