# c# get method for a readonly attribute without creating an extra attribute

Tags: c#, methods, get, attributes

I need a get method for a readonly attribute

```
 public readonly string accountNumber { get;}
```

doesn't work. Is there a way to create a get methode without creating a new extra attribute?

Comment: A property with just a `getter` is technically `readonly` by default.

Comment: Note that "attribute" in C# is very specific concept - there is no attributes shown in your post, so it is likely you use that word in some other meaning, possibly instead of "property".

Comment: Is there an error? Or, do you need to perform an operation before the value is returned?

Comment: yes indeed property @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: and yes Cs0106 The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item

Comment: Aah yes indeed @Brad M I see, thank you

Comment: This is probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833635/c-sharp-properties-how-to-use-custom-set-property-without-private-field, but since it is not clear yet what you want to achieve it may be unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of [Brad M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2089286/brad-m) was correct, if you use a get without readonly, the property is by default readonly, so you dont have to write it again. thanks